# What have old Christian writers opined about a couple living with in-laws during marriage?

Tags: marriage, early-church, church-fathers, medieval-church, parents

I understand a question has been asked and was closed on this topic previously, but I wanted to more specifically ask about Christian writings on it, preferably early ones.
Often people today use Genesis 2:24 to teach the 'leave and cleave' doctrine that a married couple should not live in the same residence as one of the in-law parents. Is this an historical interpretation of the passage? Has anyone in the church viewed the topic differently, or similarly? I.e, are there any old Christian writers who have suggested that it is acceptable for a married couple to live with parents?

Comment: The idea that Genesis *forbids* married people to share a residence with one of their parents is very much a minority view within Christianity, and has been for a while.

Comment: One possible interpretation of Gen 2:24 is that it is ok to live with the wife's parents but not with the husbands. I find this interesting, because it is the opposite of what many cultures (asian, for example) do.

Comment: Since marriage is a figure of Christ and the Church, I have never seen the main point of 'leaving' parents being 'forsaking' parents. It is the formation of a new household that is in view. Christ remains one with the Father, yet he is the Bridegroom of the Bride.

Comment: Oh dear.  My wife and I lived in my parents' basement for a couple months after we got married (overseas) before we'd saved enough money to move to an apartment.  It never occurred to me that we were violating Scripture!  Something new for confession, I guess...

Comment: @Kyralessa you weren't violating scripture. There's nothing wrong with living with your parents post-marriage.